# How to pass data to contentscript correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

i want to solve the following problem:
I have a popup window,and in `popup.html` theres a select tag:

```
<select id="chart_select">
                                <option id="chart_0" value="default">Select One</option>
                                <option id="chart_1" value="table_1">DISPLAY CLIENT VERSION USAGE CHART</option>
                                <option id="chart_2" value="table_2">DISPLAY MOST ACTIVE REALMS CHART</option>
                                <option id="chart_3" value="table_3">DISPLAY MOST ACTIVE USERS CHART</option>
                                <option id="chart_4" value="table_4">DISPLAY AVERAGE USER FRAMERATE CHART</option>
                                <option id="chart_5" value="table_5">DISPLAY AVERAGE REALM FRAMERATE CHART</option>
                                <option id="chart_6" value="table_6">DISPLAY USER LOGGED IN '' TIMES CHART</option>
                                <option id="chart_7" value="table_7">DISPLAY LOGINS per ORGANISATION</option>
                            </select>
```

So, i save to `localStorage['thetable']` the value of the selected. For example, i select `DISPLAY LOGINS per ORGANISATION` , then i save `"table_7"` to localstorage.

Then, in `background.html` i want to pass data from localstorage to my content script, like this:

```
if(localStorage.getItem('thetable') != ""){
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {thetable: localStorage.getItem('thetable') }, function(response) {
            if(response.dom != ""){
                localStorage.setItem('thedom',response.dom);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

After this, my contentscript should catch the request, and send back a response with the dom, which has been specified by an id, stored in localStorage('thetable').

```
contentscript.js:

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.thetable != "") {
        sendResponse({dom: document.getElementById(request.thetable).innerHTML});
    }
});
```

**note:** `request.thetable` should be "table_7". dom should be the innerHTML of `<table id="table_7">` of the site. It exists, i made all of these elements.

One more additional info, that i save selection value in a different file, in `popup.js`, and i save "table_7" to localStorage in this file. But localStorage is available from background.html too, so i think it shouldnt be a problem.

---

The flow:

- i select something (f.e: DISPLAY LOGINS per ORGANISATION)
- i click on `"Save Btn"` in `popup.html`, then `popup.js` saves
  "table_7" to localStorage
- then i click "Run Btn" in `popup.html`, then `popup.js` reloads
  current tab:

  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
              chrome.tabs.reload(tab.id);         });

  i do this, becouse my contentscript gathers info only when tab is
  reloaded.
- after reloading, i think, `background.html` should send Request to
  `contentscript` with the info ("table_7")
- contentscript get the DOM, from the site, f.e: `document.getElementById("table_7").innerHTML` and send back this to backgound page.

The problem is, that i get this alert, when i Run the flow:
[image]

Can somebody help me, how to fix this problem? :/ Thanks

Comment: Instead of reloading the tab to activate the Content script, I suggest to use [`chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{file:'name_of_script.js'});`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) to run the content script.

Comment: Then i get `Error during tabs.executeScript: Unknown error.
chromeHidden.handleResponse` in console. By the way, how to force background script to send the request?

Comment: Can you publish a minimal test case (including the relevant parts of the manifest file)?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

**popup.js:**
with a save button, i save selection value (="*table_7*"), and reload the selected tab:

```
$("#save_btn").click(function(){
        if($("#chart_select :selected").val()!="default"){
            var sel_val = $("#chart_select :selected").val();
            localStorage.setItem('thetable',sel_val);
            chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab){
                chrome.tabs.reload(tab.id);
            });
        }
    });
```

- As soon as site was reloaded, content_script.js gets focus:

**content_script.js:**

```
// SEND DOM structure to the background page
chrome.extension.sendRequest({ action: "waiting" },function(response){
    if(response){
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({ dom: document.getElementById(response.thetable).innerHTML });
    }
});
```

- This code sends a 'waiting' request to the background page, and wait for response, is response has come, code gets page DOM, and send it back.
  So its a nested sendRequest.

**background.html:**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.action=="waiting"){
        sendResponse({thetable:localStorage.getItem('thetable')});
        chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
            if(request.dom){
                localStorage.setItem('thedom',request.dom);
            }
        }); 
    }   
});
```

- if waiting request has come, **note**: waiting was send by the content script, send back the id ("table_7") **note**: table_7 was saved to localStorage by popup.js, after sending back id(thetable), code listens for response, if response has come, save it to localStorage. After this, "table_7"'s DOM is saved.

Finishing job, i handle data in popup.js. **note**: data is now in `localStorage('thedom')`